# How to change dependency in angular.json from a version to a local file repository

Tags: angular, package.json

```json
    "dependencies":{
"@angular/upgarde":"^13.3.9",
@mymodule/browser:"^2.0.1"
}
```

I need to change the @mymodule/browser:"^2.0.1" to some local file repository, i.e this module should read from the local module in my project.
I tried doing :@mymodule/browser:"file:../../myproject/dist/mymodule-browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it will not be going with angular.json it required Package.json to be updated. Kindly have a look at the article below. It works for me in past.

https://angular.io/cli/update